# Retrofit 2.0 value from asynch thread

Tags: java, retrofit, retrofit2

I am new into threads. And the question is: Is this correct way to extract values from async Retrofit thread. And why dont I get "0 code exit"?

Here is main code

```
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import iceandfire.Callbacks.RootCallback;
import iceandfire.Models.Root;
import iceandfire.Utils.IceFireClient;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

public class Main implements RootCallback
{
    public static void  main(String [] args)
    {
        RequestRoot(new Main());

        //this imitates UI thread
        Thread thread = new Thread()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                int counter = 5;

                while (counter >= 0)
                {
                    System.out.println("I am not retrofit Call");
                    counter -= 1;
                    try
                    {
                        Thread.sleep(1000); // 1 second
                    } catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        thread.start();
    }

    public static void RequestRoot(final RootCallback rootCallback)
    {
        Retrofit.Builder retroBuilder = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://anapioficeandfire.com/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());

        Retrofit retrofit = retroBuilder.build();

        IceFireClient client = retrofit.create(IceFireClient.class);

        Call<Root> kall = client.root();

        kall.enqueue(new Callback<Root>()
        {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Root> call, Response<Root> response)
            {
                Root bloodyRoot = response.body();
                rootCallback.onSuccess(bloodyRoot);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Root> call, Throwable t)
            {

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Root bloodyRoot)
    {
        System.out.println( new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create().toJson(bloodyRoot).toString());
    }
}
```

And callback

```
package iceandfire.Callbacks;

import iceandfire.Models.Root;

public interface RootCallback
{
    void onSuccess(Root bloodyRoot);
}
```

What I expect is: 5x messages "I am not Retrofit call";Json that I get from [iceandfireapi/root](https://anapioficeandfire.com/api) at any random time before, after, or between previous messages. And the last but not least ending of everything:"Process finished with exit code 0"

But what I get is an infinite loop: 5x messages, Json and NO exit message.

P.S. Timer thread is used to "imitate" some UI things. While retrofit is doing requests.